# SQLite Database - Create new tables and set Table name through a popup

Tags: android, database, sqlite, installed-applications

I am creating an app blocking Application and would like to know a few things:

1. How to load a list of installed apps into a database table.
2. Create a new table within the database and set the table name
   through an `EditText` field or an `AlertDialog`.
3. Call in selected apps into another activity
4. List of apps needs to have a `CheckBox` next to them to select which
   apps to carry over to another

## Completed Events

- I have already managed to populate a `ListView` with all the installed apps.
- I've set up an `AlertDialog` with everything I need so far, just need
  to know how to link that to create a new table and set the entered
  text as the table name.
- All layouts have been created and set up to accommodate everything,
  the problem just lies with the database and calling everything in

---

I hope I've provided enough details or if this makes any sense at all. Thank you in advance and I hope someone will be able to help me with this problem. If needed I can post segments of my already existing code to make things easier?

Comment: seems like your investigation goes in wrong direction, better you don't create that app :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a Android Database, I recommend to follow this tutorial:

[Android | Simple SQLite Database Tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

After this tutorial you will understand how the android database works, how you can create tables:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "title TEXT, "+
                "author TEXT )";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
}
```

And how to

1. addItemsToDatabase(Object object)
2. getItemsFromDatabase(int id)
3. getAllItemsFromDatabase()
4. updateItemInDatabase(Object object)
5. deleteItemFromDatabase(Object object)

When you know all this you can create own methods to use!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be going through this tutorial right away

Comment: This tutorial helped a lot, thank you so much... Everything is sorted :)